# Assertion failure multiplying Eigen matrices

Tags: c++, codeblocks, matrix-multiplication, eigen, least-squares

I am writing a c++ program for least square leaner regression problem in interpolation.  I use Eigen for matrix operations.  The problem I am getting is when I run the program it shows an error displaying an assertion error.  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    int nmbrOfPoints;
    cout<<" Enter the number of data points : ";
    cin>>nmbrOfPoints;

    MatrixXd matY(nmbrOfPoints,1);       //initialize matrix Y
    MatrixXd matX(nmbrOfPoints,2);       //initialize matrix X
    MatrixXd matXdup(nmbrOfPoints,2);      //initialize matrix X duplicate
    MatrixXd matAns(2,1);


    for(i=0;i<nmbrOfPoints;i++)
    {
        matX(i,0)=1;                    // storing the 1 st column of the matrix x, all 1s.
        matXdup(i,0)=1;
    }

    cout<<"Enter all sample points (x and y values ): "<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<nmbrOfPoints;i++)
    {
        cin>>matX(i,1)>>matY(i,0); // read both (x,f(x)) ,, store x values to matrix x and y values to matrix y
    }

    for(i=0;i<nmbrOfPoints;i++)
    {
        matXdup(i,1)=matX(i,1);    //copying matrix x to its duplicate
    }

    cout<<"\n \n";
    cout << matX << endl;
    cout<<"\n \n";
    cout << matY << endl;
    cout<<"\n \n";
    cout << matXdup << endl;

    // find the transpose of matrix x

    cout << "\nHere is the transposed matrix x duplicate:\n" << endl;
    matXdup.transposeInPlace();


    cout << matXdup << endl;
    cout<<"\n \n";
    cout << matX << endl;

    //find the multiplication of x and transpose of x

    matX = matX* matXdup;   // now the matrix x holds the multiplication of transpose of x and x

    cout << "\nmultiplication of x and xdup:\n" << endl;
    cout << matX << endl;
    cout<<"\n \n";

    //find the inverse of x

    double q,a,b,c,d;

    a=matX(0,0);
    b=matX(0,1);
    c=matX(1,0);
    d=matX(1,1);

    q=1/((a*d)-(b*c));

    matX(0,0) = d*q;
    matX(0,1) = b*-1*q;             //now matrix x holds the inverse of x
    matX(1,0) = c*-1*q;
    matX(1,1) = a*q;

    cout<<"\n \n";
    cout << "\n inverse of x:\n" << endl;
    cout << matX << endl;

    //find the multiplication of transpose of x(x duplicate matrix) and y

     matY = matXdup* matY;   // now the matrix x duplicate holds the multiplication of y and x transpose

    //find the multiplication of x(inverse of xt*x) and matXdup (xt*y)

    // matAns = matY* matX;

     cout << "\nfinal answers :\n" << endl;
     cout << "\n *********************:\n" << endl;

     cout << matY << endl;
     cout<<"\n \n";
     cout << matX << endl;

     cout << "\nfinal answer FINAL :\n" << endl;
     cout << "\n *********************:\n" << endl;
     matAns = matY* matX;
     cout << matAns << endl;

     /*cout<<"\n matx dup = \n";
     cout << matXdup << endl;
     cout<<"\n maty =  \n";
     cout << matY << endl;
     cout<<"\n \n";*/

     return 0;


}
```

I am getting the error from the final multiplication part which is `matAns = matY* matX`:

```
Assertion failed: a_lhs.cols() == a_rhs.rows() && "invalid matrix product" && "if you wanted a coeff-wise or a dot product use the respective explicit functions"
```

When I remove that statement code works. Up to that point the code works fine. Can someone explain me what is assertion problem and how to fix it here?

Comment: What is the error? Eigen assertions usually have useful information in them.

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb` on Linux).

Comment: In general an assertion error indicates that you violated the 'contract' of the function you called in some way. You haven't provided much detail but since you are doing matrix multiplication I would guess that you've picked two matrices whose size means they cannot be multiplied.

Comment: I am using codeblocks, so how can I compile with warnings.

Comment: error says Assertion failed: a_lhs.cols() == a_rhs.rows() && "invalid matrix product" && "i
f you wanted a coeff-wise or a dot product use the respective explicit functions

Comment: @buddhiweerasinghe Exactly like I said, you picked two matrices which can't be multipled because matY.cols() != matX.rows().

Comment: @john I am multiplying a 2*2 matrix with a 2*1 matrix. When I multiply them using an another simple program it works

Comment: @buddhiweerasinghe What can I say, eigen disagrees with you. Are you sure you haven't got your rows and columns mixed up?

Comment: @buddhiweerasinghe I think if you look at your code you'll see you are multiplying a 2x1 matrix by a 2x2 matrix, which is a completely different thing.

Comment: Thank u all. I solved it. I just had to interchange the parameters of the multiplication statement. Thank u all again

Comment: @buddhiweerasinghe Please next time, include complete error messages from the start.

Answer (score 3):

`matY` is a 2x1 vector and `matX` is a NxN matrix, so the product `matY * matX` is invalid. Are you sure you don't want to compute `matX` as:

```
matX = matXdup * matX;
```

and matAns as:

```
matAns = matX * matY;
```

?

BTW, no need to explicitly transpose `matXdup` with `transposeInPlace`, you can directly do:

```
matX = matXdup.transpose() * matX;
```

Moreover, when a dimension is known at compiletime and that this dimension is very small, better specify it. For instance, matY should rather be a VectorXd. The result of `matXdup.transpose() * matX` should rather be stored in a `Matrix2d` object. Then call `inverse()` instead of writing your own inverse routine (you need to include `<Eigen/LU>`:

```
Matrix2d XX = matXdup.transpose() * matX; 
Vector2d Y = matXdup * matY;
Vector2d ans = XX.inverse() * Y;
```